# NIntegrate returns zero for non zero integrand, 4d Integration

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to calculate the following integral.

```
sigma1 = 10.0; sigma2 = 5.0; delta = 0.5;
t[x1_, y1_, x_, y_] := 100*HeavisideLambda[sigma1^-1*(x - x1), sigma2^-1*(y - y1)];
B2[x1_, y1_, x_, y_] := HeavisideTheta[(delta/2)^2 - (x - x1)^2, (delta/2)^2 - (y - y1)^2];
trans[x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_] :=
    NIntegrate[B2[x1, y1, xz, yz]*t[xz, yz, xp, yp]*
       (B2[x2, y2, xz, yz] - B2[x2, y2, xp, yp]),
        {xp, x2 - 2.0*sigma1, x2 + 2.0*sigma1},
        {yp, y2 - 2.0*sigma2, y2 + 2.0*sigma2},
        {xz, x1 - 0.5*delta, x1 + 0.5*delta}, 
        {yz, y1 - 0.5*delta, y1 + 0.5*delta},
     WorkingPrecision -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 8, MinRecursion -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 100];
```

I am interested in the value of the integral for the following inputs:

```
trans[0, 0, delta, 0]
```

Here is my problem: for values of delta greater than 0.5 (I tried 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 07, 0.6, 0.515), the result is a negative number, and it takes some time for *Mathematica* to come up with the result. For any value of delta smaller than 0.5, *Mathematica* immediately returns 0, and doesn't give any hints about what is wrong.

This is a part of a refinement study and I need to choose smaller and smaller values for delta. Do you know how I can make this work?

Comment: works for me: `trans[0,0,1/4,0] -> 624.99 `.  You had some strange character instead of a semicolon after delta=0.5 by the way.

Comment: yes that works for me too, but what i need is trans[0,0,delta,0]. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

The Heaviside functions are essentially piecewise functions, and `NIntegrate` knows how to handle `Piecewise` functions but not Heaviside functions.  In particular, it will analyze the domain of `Piecewise` functions and adjust its sampling accordingly.  Here are two rules for conversion, ignoring boundary points which won't affect the integral anyway:

```
heaviside2piecewise = {
   HeavisideTheta -> (Piecewise[{{1, #1 > 0 && #2 > 0}}, 0] &),
   HeavisideLambda -> (Piecewise[{{#1 + 1, -1 < #1 < 0}, {1 - #1, 0 <= #1 < 1}}, 0] *
       Piecewise[{{#2 + 1, -1 < #2 < 0}, {1 - #2, 0 <= #2 < 1}}, 0] &)};
```

Then we can apply them to the integrand:

```
trans[x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_] := NIntegrate[
  B2[x1, y1, xz, yz] * t[xz, yz, xp, yp] * (B2[x2, y2, xz, yz] - B2[x2, y2, xp, yp]) /. 
    heaviside2piecewise,
  {xp, x2 - 2.0*sigma1, x2 + 2.0*sigma1},
  {yp, y2 - 2.0*sigma2, y2 + 2.0*sigma2},
  {xz, x1 - 0.5*delta, x1 + 0.5*delta},
  {yz, y1 - 0.5*delta, y1 + 0.5*delta}]
```

It evaluates rather quickly, too:

```
trans[0, 0, delta, 0]
(* -5.73958 *)

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]; (* V10 *)
trans[0, 0, delta, 0] // AccurateTiming
(* 0.0757289 *)
```

**Exact solution**

In fact, this integral may be solved exactly, with exact values for the parameters.

```
transExact[x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_] := Integrate[
  B2[x1, y1, xz, yz] * t[xz, yz, xp, yp] * (B2[x2, y2, xz, yz] - B2[x2, y2, xp, yp]) /. 
    heaviside2piecewise,
  {xp, x2 - 2*sigma1, x2 + 2*sigma1},
  {yp, y2 - 2*sigma2, y2 + 2*sigma2},
  {xz, x1 - 1/2*delta, x1 + 1/2*delta},
  {yz, y1 - 1/2*delta, y1 + 1/2*delta}];

transExact[0, 0, delta, 0]
(* -(551/96) *)
```

Answer (score 0):

ah, you are right for that condition: `B2[x2, y2, xz, yz]` and  `B2[x2, y2, xp, yp]` are returning 0 for every *sample* point in the domain. This is not so much an answer but I thought i may be useful to show how to use `EvaluationMonitor`and `Reap/Sow` to get at this:

```
 trans[x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_] :=
        NIntegrate[B2[x1, y1, xz, yz]*t[xz, yz, xp, yp]*
        ((b21 = B2[x2, y2, xz, yz]) - (b22 = B2[x2, y2, xp, yp])),
          {xp, x2 - 2.0*sigma1, x2 + 2.0*sigma1},
          {yp, y2 - 2.0*sigma2, y2 + 2.0*sigma2},
          {xz, x1 - 0.5*delta, x1 + 0.5*delta},
          {yz, y1 - 0.5*delta, y1 + 0.5*delta},
             WorkingPrecision -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 8, MinRecursion -> 8, 
             MaxRecursion -> 100, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{b21, b22}]];     

 (First@Last@Reap[trans[0, 0, delta, 0]])
```

> result 14,000 {0,0}'s

I didn't get so far as studying why this happens, but use of the same the symbol `x1` for different things makes it a little confusing to read.

### edit

looking at this a little deeper, i suspect you may have a situation where the integrand is zero everywhere except for a small region. `NIntegrate` samples over a pretty coarse grid, doesn't happen to hit any non-zero points and stops.  Try some of the other integration `Methods`.( `MinRecursion` doesnt seem to do anything BTW )  You might also see if you can id the nonzero region and tighten the integration limits.

Comment: I think the integral limits are already as tight as possible, Based on the shape of "t" and "B2".
I also think that NIntegrate doesn't sample point where it should, but I don't know how to make it do that. Do you have any specific method in mind?